# How to specify an integer column as unsigned?

Tags: jdo, unsigned, datanucleus

Assume the following class

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION, detachable = "true")
public class TclRequest2 {
    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    @Persistent(column = "userid")
    @Column(defaultValue = "1", jdbcType = "INTEGER", length = 11, allowsNull = "false", extensions = {})
    private Member member;
    //Getters and setters
}
```

The "Member" field's column should be translated into an integer column. But that column will have to create a foreign-key constraint to point at "Member"'s primary key field which has the type

```
INT(11) UNSIGNED
```

I figured out how to make the first part as shown but I have no idea how to specify that the field should be `UNSIGNED` !

Thank you.